# limit - show that in infinity function grow faster that other function

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, logarithms, infinity

given two function:

1. $x\:\le\:b\cdot \log\left(x\right)\:$
2. $x\:\le\:x\cdot \:\log\left(x\right)\:$

i want to show that $b\cdot \:\log\left(x\right)\:\le \:x\cdot  \log\left(x\right)\:$

I made a graph of these 2 functions, you can clearly see that this is true, at infinity, this equation (2) is always above this equation (1)

[image]

I was thinking of showing the limit at infinity:
$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\left(b\cdot \:\log\left(x\right)\:\right)/\left(\:x\cdot \:\log\left(x\right)\:\right)\right) = 0$

I'm not sure if this is a correct way to do it, am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is *a* correct way, which basically states that $b\cdot ln(x)$ gets *infinitely smaller* than $x\cdot ln(x)$ when $x$ grows *infinitely large*. Or more informally, the more you blow $x$ up, the value of $b\cdot ln(x)$ will be *more* negligible than $x\cdot \ln(x)$.

This can be easily shown using the way you stated:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{b\cdot \ln(x)}{x\cdot \ln(x)} $$
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{b}{x} $$
$$ = 0$$ since $b$ is just a constant.